# Определить положение зрачка глаза

Tags: android

Всем привет.

Нужно определить положение зрачка с помощью фронтальной камеры. Android предоставляет методы для определения центра левого (правого) глаза. А как можно следить именно за движением зрачка? Возможно кто то сталкивался с такой задачей, подскажите куда копнуть.

Спасибо.

Comment: Эт надо мелко ребристое изображение выводить на экран для начала, иначе зрачок будет постоянно дёргаться при движении... и толку о положения не будет :-)

Answer (score 3):

Используйте библиотеку компьютерного зрения OpenCV для Андроид.

Comment: Будем считать, что фраза топикстартера "подскажите куда копнуть" дала вам карт-бланш на однострочный ответ. Обычно такое рекомендуется к удалению из-за длины. Либо [пишется в комментариях](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4578/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8). Ладно, "выглядит нормально" и даже upvote.

Comment: @AK, ок буду знать. К моменту написания ответа у меня не было соответствующих привилегий для комментирования вопросов.

Comment: Главное не количество букв, а смысл слов.

Answer (score 2):

В OpenCV есть несколько методов для выявления глаза - начать можно с этой [статьи](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/db/d28/tutorial_cascade_classifier.html). 
Зрачок вам придется искать уже самостоятельно, выделив фрагмент кадра, соответствующий глазу. Довольно несложно будет найти центр зрачка по градиенту - искать по пикселам вправо-влево от центра глаза пока не доберетесь до белка - вот вам и глазное яблоко, ну как пример в лоб. 
Трудности будут совсем другого плана - по монокулярному изображению будет невозможно установить с достаточной точностью углы поворота и наклона головы.

Чтобы решить Вашу задачу, необходима прежде всего 3D-реконструкция положения головы (координаты и поза) относительно камеры, а потом уже зрачок...